# How to compare file with its previous version in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, diff, tortoisegit

I used git bisect to locate the commit that broke stuff. Now I want to compare file with its previous version but when I right click a file in Log Messages window I have only "Compare with base" and "Compare with working tree" and that's useless for me.

**How can I easily compare a file from some old commit with its previous version?**

I just want to see what was added/deleted in that particular commit in that file. This what TortoiseSvn normally does when you double click a file in Log Messages window.
I would prefer to get that outcome using TortoiseGit and WinMerge but if its not possible any other tool is also good.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i recommends You to use cli, its much more easy to use it to this kind of tasks: git diff <commit_hash_before>..<commit_hash_after> -- path/to/file

Comment: That's one way of doing this but not very convenient also console diff feels awkward. This helped a bit http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#External-Merge-and-Diff-Tools

Comment: Believe me. I was using GUI before Years too. Its only about habits. Git cli is not easy to conquer but when you'll be using it for about a Year, You will never want to come back into any GUI tool.

Answer (score 3):

git diff HEAD^

HEAD is the latest version, and ^ means "prior".  For example, HEAD^^ means 2 back.